# Redirect traffic from one IP address

Tags: iptables, ip, virtual-machines, redirection

A have a root server with 2 static IP address which are both connected to one interface (eth0 and eth0:1). Now I need to redirect all incoming traffic from one IP address to a VM on the same PC. The VM has it's own local IP address within a virtual switch. (It is reachable from the "root computer"). I've already talked to the provider and he admit that it is possible with NATing but however isn't allowed to give me more detailed instruction. 
What I already tried:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -d 85.214.XXX.XXX -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.122.58

iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0:1 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.122.58
```

Both doesn't work. The VM it's self has internet access over one IP address. (Pings from the VM are successful). The problem is, that the incoming traffic (for example 85.214.XXX.XXX:80) is still handled by the "root computer" so it need to be redirected to the VM. Requests over the other IP address (85.12.XXX.XXX:80)  must not be redirected. Port 80 was just an example port. There are more ports that http needed.

***EDIT1:*** After using the first command, the traffic doesn't get handled by the "root server" but however does not reach the VM either.

***EDIT2:***
ip -br link:

    `lo               UNKNOWN        00:00:00:00:00:00 
    eth0             UP             ac:1f:6b:21:ea:14 
    eth1             DOWN           ac:1f:6b:21:ea:15 
    virbr0           UP             52:54:00:07:80:05 
    virbr0-nic       DOWN           52:54:00:07:80:05 
    vnet0            UNKNOWN        fe:00:a3:b0:56:10`

Ip -br adress:

    `lo               UNKNOWN        127.0.0.1/8 ::1/128
    eth0             UP             81.169.XXX.XXX/32 85.214.XXX.XXX/32 fe80::ae1f:6bff:fe21:XXXX/64
    eth1             DOWN
    virbr0           UP             192.168.122.1/24
    virbr0-nic       DOWN
    vnet0            UNKNOWN        fe80::fc00:a3ff:feb0:5610/64`

Ip route:

    `default via 81.169.192.1 dev eth0
    81.169.192.1 dev eth0  scope link
    169.254.0.0/16 dev eth0  scope link  metric 1000
    192.168.122.0/24 dev virbr0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.122.1`

Ip-adress -c: iptables-save -c

    `# Generated by iptables-save v1.6.0 on Tue Jun 26 21:12:21 2018
    *nat
    :PREROUTING ACCEPT [77:5491]
    :INPUT ACCEPT [57:4459]
    :OUTPUT ACCEPT [26:1644]
    :POSTROUTING ACCEPT [26:1644]
    [36:1868] -A PREROUTING -d 85.214.XXX.XXX/32 -p tcp -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.122.58
    [326:23798] -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.122.0/24 -d 224.0.0.0/24 -j RETURN
    [0:0] -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.122.0/24 -d 255.255.255.255/32 -j RETURN
    [70:4104] -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.122.0/24 ! -d 192.168.122.0/24 -p tcp -j MASQUERADE --to-ports 1024-65535
    [2384:181184] -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.122.0/24 ! -d 192.168.122.0/24 -p udp -j MASQUERADE --to-ports 1024-65535
    [1:84] -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.122.0/24 ! -d 192.168.122.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
    [4:240] -A POSTROUTING -d 192.168.122.58/32 -j SNAT --to-source 85.214.XXX.XXX
    COMMIT
    # Completed on Tue Jun 26 21:12:21 2018
    # Generated by iptables-save v1.6.0 on Tue Jun 26 21:12:21 2018
    *mangle
    :PREROUTING ACCEPT [8612376:1647699647]
    :INPUT ACCEPT [7968616:1098054721]
    :FORWARD ACCEPT [642923:549577951]
    :OUTPUT ACCEPT [7286018:1062313751]
    :POSTROUTING ACCEPT [7752855:1602990616]
    [363:121944] -A POSTROUTING -o virbr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 68 -j CHECKSUM --checksum-fill
    COMMIT
    # Completed on Tue Jun 26 21:12:21 2018
    # Generated by iptables-save v1.6.0 on Tue Jun 26 21:12:21 2018
    *filter
    :INPUT DROP [0:0]
    :FORWARD DROP [0:0]
    :OUTPUT DROP [0:0]
    :f2b-plesk-modsecurity - [0:0]
    [82390:7025055] -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 993 -j ACCEPT
    [18:720] -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 106 -j DROP
    [2488:104592] -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 3306 -j DROP
    [153:6168] -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 5432 -j DROP
    [9:360] -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 9008 -j DROP
    [41:1784] -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 9080 -j DROP
    [252:20165] -A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 137 -j DROP
    [10772:2676517] -A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 138 -j DROP
    [488:21600] -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 139 -j DROP
    [849142:43736264] -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 445 -j DROP
    [68:2856] -A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 1194 -j DROP
    [39259:2663130] -A INPUT -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j DROP
    [15817:947524] -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j DROP
    [974:36333] -A INPUT -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8/0 -j ACCEPT
    [5763490:719804706] -A INPUT -j ACCEPT
    [327455:532369669] -A FORWARD -d 192.168.122.0/24 -o virbr0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
    [145660:7917349] -A FORWARD -s 192.168.122.0/24 -i virbr0 -j ACCEPT
    [0:0] -A FORWARD -i virbr0 -o virbr0 -j ACCEPT
    [29309:1533140] -A FORWARD -o virbr0 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
    [0:0] -A FORWARD -i virbr0 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
    [0:0] -A FORWARD -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
    [249:11394] -A FORWARD -p tcp -m tcp ! --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -m state --state NEW -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset
    [3875:171296] -A FORWARD -m state --state INVALID -j DROP
    [0:0] -A FORWARD -i lo -o lo -j ACCEPT
    [582365:31456904] -A FORWARD -j DROP
    [363:121944] -A OUTPUT -o virbr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 68 -j ACCEPT
    [12150865:2418557344] -A OUTPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
    [24:5299] -A OUTPUT -p tcp -m tcp ! --tcp-flags FIN,SYN,RST,ACK SYN -m state --state NEW -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset
    [12746:706295] -A OUTPUT -m state --state INVALID -j DROP
    [494443:29667994] -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
    [408707:30248531] -A OUTPUT -j ACCEPT
    [68:6175] -A f2b-plesk-modsecurity -j RETURN
    COMMIT
    # Completed on Tue Jun 26 21:12:21 2018`

And on the VM:

ip route:

    `default via 192.168.122.1 dev ens3
    169.254.0.0/16 dev ens3 scope link metric 1000
    192.168.122.0/24 dev ens3 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.122.58`

Comment: Have you enabled forwarding with with sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.all.forwarding=1?

Comment: Yes I did. Read my edit1 for more information

Comment: You should provide several network informations for both systems (2nd being the VM) to avoid people having to guess what's wrong: `ip -br link; ip -br address; ip route; iptables-save -c`. Don't use ifconfig, it confuses people when using multiple IPs (eg, `eth0:1`, an artefact from ifconfig times, will probably never match in iptables)

Comment: Yep, iptables-save would be beneficial. Especially the filter table FORWARD  policy and chain.

Comment: I added all information :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `FORWARD` rules allow VM initiated traffic, outgoing and reply, with these rules:

```
-A FORWARD -d 192.168.122.0/24 -o virbr0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT #reply traffic to the VM
-A FORWARD -s 192.168.122.0/24 -i virbr0 -j ACCEPT #VM initiated
```

What they don't allow is incoming traffic, as the counter's high value hints in the next `FORWARD` rule:

```
[29309:1533140] -A FORWARD -o virbr0 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
```

That's good for security but you'll have to add exceptions.

**UPDATE**: redirect all traffic, not just a few ports.

The redirection itself:

```
iptables -t nat -I PREROUTING -d 85.214.XXX.XXX -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.122.58
```

This will redirect all protocols (icmp, tcp, udp (possibly others)), you can add as you wrote initially `-p tcp` to limit it to tcp.

You have to enable the redirected traffic in the `FORWARD` chain, since once the traffic is `DNAT`ed, it becomes routed, so is subject to the `FORWARD` chain (and no more to the `INPUT` chain). At the same time, to guard against any local routing misuse (by the default gateway for example), you can limit this to `DNAT`ed traffic only, by querying conntrack (marking packets in the mangle table and checking them here would have worked too):

```
iptables -I FORWARD -d 192.168.122.58 -m conntrack --ctstate DNAT -j ACCEPT
```

Notice the `-I`. Since you're competing with the VM's provider rules (probably virt-manager), you have to take care your exception rules come before the `DROP`/`REJECT` rules. Optimally it could come after the `... RELATED,ESTABLISHED ...` rule, but you can deal with that later.

Note also that for the same reason (rule coming too late), your VM's outgoing traffic is not using its dedicated IP but the host's IP: the `SNAT` rule comes too late, after the generic `MASQUERADE` rule. You have to insert it with a `-I` and not a `-A` too until you figure out how to integrate this with (probably?) virt-manager.
AND, also, there's an error in this rule anyway, it should be using `-s` not `-d` as in:

```
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -s 192.168.122.58/32 ! -d 192.168.122.0/24 -j SNAT --to-source 85.214.XXX.XXX
```

Whenever (probably?) virt-manager reinserts its rule (restart etc.), you should have a look again at your rules to see if everything is still in an order allowing what you intend.

That would be out of the scope of this Q/A to address virt-manager integration. Have a look there for example:

[Networking - Libvirt Wiki - Forwarding Incoming Connections](https://wiki.libvirt.org/page/Networking#Forwarding_Incoming_Connections)

Comment: So you mean it's not possible to redirect all ports from the second IP address to the VM?

Comment: I just didn't get you wanted to redirect all traffic. I changed the answer.

Comment: @MarvinX   Just for information, there can probably be an other completely different method using macvlan or ipvlan (in case macvlan is blocked by the hosting provider): the container or VM might then "own" directly the IP address without NAT involved. I'd know usage for container (using ip link set netns ... to move the interface) , not much for a VM. You can have a look there: [Macvlan and IPvlan basics](https://sreeninet.wordpress.com/2016/05/29/macvlan-and-ipvlan/)

Comment: @MarvinX confused: the answer about NAT or the comment about ipvlan (for a qemu VM it appears to be ipvtap) ?